# Rotating through array continuously with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I need to fade items from an array in and out continuously and I'm currently doing it as such:

```
var rotateHint = function() {
var hints = ['fe','fi','fo','fum'];
var hint;
var p = (function() {
    if (!hint || !hint.length) hint = hints.slice();
         return hint.splice(Math.random() * hint.length | 0, 1);
}())
$('#hint').text(p) //THE ERROR IS HERE...
          .fadeIn()
          .delay(1000)
          .fadeOut(200,function(){ 
            rotateHint();
            })
};
```

However it seems that .text(p) isn't working however if I look at p with an alert(p) the output is sound.

Comment: What element is `#hint`? Have you tried using `html()` instead of `text()` instead?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle on jsfiddle.net showing the issue?

Comment: #hint is a simple <div></div> and yes I've also tried html()..

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/fpHKq/

Comment: yeh seems my jQuery is below 1.7 thanks guys!!

Comment: It would be better to fix it so that you pass an actual string instead of an array (`.text(p[0])`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be working only from jQuery 1.7
Previous versions throw an error

But it's kind of weird to do a text() on an array no?

Answer (score -1):

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmjsU/3/). Seems it is already working.

For some added value I optimized your JavaScript code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="hint"></div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function() {
    var hints = ['fe', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum']
      , p;

    (function rotateHint() {
        p = hints[Math.round(Math.random() * hints.length)];

        $('#hint').text(p).fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(200, rotateHint);
    }());

}());​
```

Works on Safari 6, FireFox 14 and Chrome 21 Beta